# How to delete multiple folders from SharePoint using PowerAutomate

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I was able to delete multiple files, but I would like to know how to use PowerAutomate to delete multiple folders in a SharePoint library at once, as the library may have folders as well as files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use use the "Get files" SharePoint action, add the condition if ISFolder = true, delete the item.  Note: in delete item action, you need to enter custom value. Like this:

[image]